# Why automatic switching of themes based on current time is deprecated in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-appcompat

[image]

I am confused regarding [AppCompactDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#MODE_NIGHT_AUTO).

Why does it tell me to not use MODE_NIGHT_AUTO but MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME which is also deprecated? And why is it unfavorable behavior in the first place to base automatic theme switching on the current time?

Comment: I would like an option like this: Respect day/night theme by system (user settings), but at the night (respect time) use night theme.